# send link using php mail() function

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

User should get a email in the format:-----
Copy the token:    xxxxx    And paste it in this *Link* -----
My codes:

```
$message="Copy the token:       ".
            token_generator(10)."       ".
            "And paste it in the link  "."<a href='recover_pass_get_mail.php'>Link</a>";
```

where xxxxx is returned by token_generator(10) function.
but user gets in the format code is written

Comment: What exactly is your error?

Comment: user get ---  Copy the token:      xxxxx      And paste it in the link  <a href='recover_pass_get_mail.php'>Link</a>

Comment: which is not expected

Comment: @ParthoProtim could you attach your code which send the email

Comment: $subject="Password Recovery";
        $message="Copy the token:       ".
                token_generator(10)."       ".
                "And paste it in the link  "."<a href='recover_pass_get_mail.php'>Link</a>";
            $from="xyz";
        mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems like your email function doesn't have good react with html tags, you probably missing this in you'r `$header` object.

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

read this,
https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

it has great explanation

Comment: you want me to copy paste that context from this site ? the main problem is that people doesn't google before they open new question.

Comment: No, you should add some code from that site and explain it how, why, when it works best of OP based on the link you are posting.

Comment: i googled a good many times. i tried as they said. even answers from stack overflow doesn't work for me. but those answers worked for the askers.

Comment: well, @ParthoProtim I've added the main thing you probably missing.

Comment: where i will put $headers  ? @Danny

Comment: in your mail function
`mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` the objects names saying it all ..

Answer (score 2):

There is many points you should think about them .. you can notice them in the following example code:

```
<?php

$fromTitle = "From Title";
$emailFrom = 'example_from@gmail.com';
$emailTo   = 'example_to@gmail.com';
$token = token_generator(10);

$subject = "Password Recovery"; 
$message = "Copy the token: $token And paste it in the link <a href='recover_pass_get_mail.php'>Link</a>";
$random_hash = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: $fromTitle <$emailFrom>\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$emailFrom."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$random_hash."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is token email.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$random_hash."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";

@mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $header);   


?>
```

Comment: I don't know why someone make vote down .. if there is some thing wrong just let us know .. my answer is tested and works correctly

Comment: is `token_generator(10)` echoing anything?

Comment: yes i agree we must use variable for this .. i will change my answer .. and your function token_generator as i think should return the token and not echo the token

Comment: Upvoted. This is a great and complete answer. The only things I want to mention are: I think you are misusing boundary (see this article by Kevin McMahon: http://goo.gl/Li1jJ); and `$from` should be changed to `$fromTitle` in `$header = "From: ".$from // ...` (I've submitted an edit to your answer for this). Aside from that, great answer. Prior to reading this, I didn't even know about the `multipart/mixed` MIME type.

Comment: @SpencerDoak okay let me clear with you ,, i faced many problems before with send email ,, and after searching i found this as the best solution for me but i do not know what is the meaning of each stuff ,, you know ,, sometimes you do not have time ,, you just need to solve the issue and save your day .. i must read more about it ;)

Comment: @MohammadAlabed, understandable. And if it works, then it works :P I was just curious about `boundary` and I noticed the W3C's protocol standards say it's a bit different. Then the article by Kevin McMahon cleared it up for me. That all said, in my opinion, this is still the best answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your strings, however, here are a few things to consider here:

First all you might want to (just as a matter of practice) assign `token_generator(10)` to a variable on your script.

Something like this

```
$token = token_generator(10)
```

and pass `$token` to the script

Secondly you are having some trouble with the strings in your email.  You don't need to wrap your link in `a href` tags (in fact it will be a problem if the user does not have HTML email turned on (as many do not).  Just post the link itself.

Thirdly, why not just attach the token to the URL?  It's an easier step for the user.    Here's an example:

```
$message="Follow this link: http://(url)recover_pass_get_mail.php?token=$token";
```

and then you can just get the token from the URL using

```
$_GET['token'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
$myToken = token_generator(10);
$message="Copy the token: $myToken And paste it in the link <a href='recover_pass_get_mail.php'>Link</a>";
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/kE5DFv)

Comment: How will this work for users  who do not use HTML mail?

Comment: yes. but still i get :  ......And paste it in the link <a href='recover_pass_get_mail.php'>Link</a>

Comment: @PedroLobito, there's no indication that `token_generator()` isn't working. The issue is that *`<a href='recover_pass_get_mail.php'>Link</a>`* is showing up as plain text rather than formatted HTML. the functionality of `token_generator()` is unrelated. For all intents and purposes, `token_generator()` can be ignored and we can just imagine that Partho is sending some arbitrary link (e.g., *`<a href='http://example.com/random'>Click for Adventure</a>`*). As such, you can ignore the fact that `token_generator()` even exists as it is truly irrelevant to the problem.