# PHP issue sending mail with link and get information

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send some text with a link with php mail() as plain text. The link looks like this https://example.com?en=1509
But in the mail I receive the link looks like this https://example.com?en09. If I send an '=' alone it is no problem but if I have an equal and a number it is not working anymore.

Here is the code I use for sending the mail:

```
$header[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$header[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
$header[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable';
$header[] = $from;

mail($mail,$titel, $text, implode("\r\n",$header));
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

[Edit]

If I take a look at the Thunderbird mail source code everything is okay but it is displayed wrong.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
From: admin <admin@example.com>
Message-Id: <20160514213835.DD631480051D@example.com>
Date: Sat, 14 May 2016 23:38:35 +0200 (CEST)

https://example.com?en=1545
```

I also tried to send the link as text/html and to wrap it into a proper  tag but nothing worked. The link is always broken.

Thanks

Comment: try to add a header 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"; 
instead of 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8';

Comment: posssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711700/php-mail-how-to-put-an-html-link-in-an-email and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733471/send-link-using-php-mail-function

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I already tried that. It is not helping. Also it is not a duplicate of the two mentioned question because I do not want to send a href link, I want to send the plain link.

Comment: Show your content you are sending in email

Comment: I did a test mail with just that link as you can see above.

Unfortunately it is not Thunderbird. On my mobile the links is also broken. I can trick Thunderbird in displaying the right link by adding ?en=R1545 but that does not work on my mobile...

Comment: Did you change the headers to text/html ?

Comment: Hi Poria, thanks for looking into this. Yes, I already have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking through the source code of different mails I found this line in the header:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

After changing my PHP header to this:

```
$header[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$header[] = 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
$header[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit';
$header[] = $from;

mail($mail,$titel, $text, implode("\r\n",$header));
```

I got it working. Links are displayed correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a header

`$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";`

instead of `'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8';`

Hope it helps !